# how to assign associative array value in a smarty 2.x template without php script

Tags: php, arrays, templates, smarty, associative

how to assign associative array value to a variable say,

```
{* $a = array('key1'=>123) *}
{assign var="a.key2" value=234}
```

without pre-assigning in php script or using a {php} tag?

Comment: Smarty is a template engine, so avoid using {php} tags in smarty

Answer (score 3):

smarty code

```
{assign var="keys" value=','|explode:'key1,key2,key3'}
{assign var="values" value=','|explode:'value1,value2,value3'}

{assign var="a" value=$keys|@array_combine:$values}


{foreach from=$a item="value" key="key"}

{$key} | {$value}<br>

{/foreach}
and {$a.key2}
```

result

```
key1 | value1
key2 | value2
key3 | value3
and value2
```